# A polynomial with real coefficients expressible as sum of squares of two polynomials will have not all roots as real.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Let $f$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. Show that all the
>   roots of $f$ are real if and only if $f^2$ cannot be written as
>   $$f^2=g^2+h^2$$ where $g$ and $h$ are polynomials with real
>   coefficients, $deg(g)\neq deg(h)$ and $g,h\neq 0$

I showed in one direction that if $f$ can be written in this form then all roots won't be real, here is how

Lets assume that $f$ has all roots real and let $f(x)=a(x-x_1)...(x-x_n)$. Then we have $f^2(x)=g^2(x)+h^2(x)$ becomes $$a^2(x-x_1)^2...(x-x_n)^2=g^2(x)+h^2(x)$$ Clearly $(g(x_i))^2+(h(x_i))^2=0$ thus $g(x_i)=0$ and $h(x_i)=0$, so $f|g$ and $f|h$. let $g=g'f$ and $h=h'f$ then $$(h'(x))^2+(g'(x))^2=1$$ which cant be true since not both are simultaneously constant.

Now for the other direction we need to show that if all roots are not real then the polynomial is expressible as sum of squares. I am having difficulties on this, can the same argument be modified for the purpose? Please give hints or solutions for the second part.

Comment: Hidden in my solution is a key idea, it is $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know a little bit about real polynomials.

Every real polynomial can be factored into irreducible real polynomials, and they are of two different forms :

- $(x-a)$
- $(x-a)^2+b^2$ with $b$ non-zero

---

So if not all of the roots of $f(x)$ are real then it can be factored as follows:

$f(x)=g(x)[(x-a)^2+b^2]$

So $f(x)^2=g(x)^2[ (x-a)^4+2(x-a)^2b^2+b^4]=g(x)^2[((x-a)^2-b^2)^2+(2(x-a)b)^2]=[g(x)((x-a)^2-b^2)]^2+[g(x)2(x-a)b]^2$.

Comment: do you mean that any real polynomial whose not all zeroes are real can be written as $f(x)=a(x-l_1)^{t_1}...(x-l_r)^{t_r}(x^2+b_1x+c_1)^{k_1}...(x^2+b_sx+c_s)^{k_s}$?

Comment: yes,  I do, I changed $f'$ with $g$ to avoid confusion. It can be expressed as you said, but we can multiply all of the other factors and just call it $g$